# Keras validation generator evaluation metrics

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to do a binary classification on a dataset of 1D signals. I'm using `keras 2.2.4` backed by `tensorflow 1.12.0` to accomplish this task. I need to apply a custom metric on my validation data so I created the `Metrics` class. Here is the main piece of code I'm using:

```
train_gen = load.data_generator(batch_size, preproc, *train)
dev_gen = load.data_generator(batch_size, preproc, *dev)
valid_metrics = Metrics(dev_gen, len(dev[0]) // batch_size, batch_size)
model.fit_generator(train_gen,
      steps_per_epoch=len(train[0]) // batch_size,
      epochs=MAX_EPOCHS,
      validation_data=dev_gen,
      validation_steps=len(dev[0]) // batch_size,
      callbacks=[valid_metrics, checkpointer, reduce_lr, tensorboard])


class Metrics(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, val_data, step, batch_size=20):
        self.validation_data = val_data
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.validation_step = step
        print('validation_step  ' + str(step))

    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self._rocdata_perclass = []
        self._prdata_perclass = []
        self._accdata = []

    def on_epoch_end(self, batch, logs={}):

        for batch_index in range(self.validation_step):
            xVal, yVal = next(self.validation_data)
            predictions = self.model.predict(xVal)
            print(predictions.shape)
            print(yVal.shape)

****** Training output*****
1/12 [=>............................] - ETA: 2:27 - loss: 1.1788 - acc: 0.5113
 x shape (16, 38400, 1)
 y shape (16, 150, 2)
 2/12 [====>.........................] - ETA: 1:11 - loss: 2.1305 - acc: 0.4668 
 x shape (16, 38144, 1)
 y shape (16, 149, 2)
 3/12 [======>.......................] - ETA: 44s - loss: 2.0981 - acc: 0.4302
 x shape (16, 38400, 1)
 y shape (16, 150, 2)
 4/12 [=========>....................] - ETA: 30s - loss: 1.8517 - acc: 0.3823 
 x shape (16, 38400, 1)
 y shape (16, 150, 2)
 5/12 [===========>..................] - ETA: 21s - loss: 1.6540 - acc: 0.4184
 x shape (16, 38144, 1)
 y shape (16, 149, 2)
 6/12 [==============>...............] - ETA: 16s - loss: 1.5060 - acc: 0.4350
 x shape (16, 38912, 1)
 y shape (16, 152, 2)
 7/12 [================>.............] - ETA: 12s - loss: 1.4447 - acc: 0.3977
 x shape (16, 38400, 1)
 y shape (16, 150, 2)
 8/12 [===================>..........] - ETA: 8s - loss: 1.3394 - acc: 0.4423
 x shape (16, 41472, 1)
 y shape (16, 162, 2)
 9/12 [=====================>........] - ETA: 6s - loss: 1.2576 - acc: 0.4718
 x shape (16, 37888, 1)
 y shape (16, 148, 2)
10/12 [========================>.....] - ETA: 3s - loss: 1.1878 - acc: 0.5138
 x shape (16, 39424, 1)
 y shape (16, 154, 2)
11/12 [==========================>...] - ETA: 1s - loss: 1.1355 - acc: 0.5395
 x shape (16, 39168, 1)
 y shape (16, 153, 2)
```

As you can see in the output of the training above, the shape of each batch input (x) and output (y) is different from one another because I'm padding the data to have the same length. One signal has `n classes of dimension 2`. My question is related to the evaluation I need to make on the validation data using the `Metrics` class. Since I have different input and output shapes for each batch for validation as well, how can I evaluate the whole validation data at one time using Area under the ROC curve? As you can see in the code above, I can only use batches of the validation whereas I need the whole validation data so I can be able to evaluate it once.

```
******* Validation Metric output ********
x shape (16, 41984, 1)
y shape (16, 164, 2)
x shape (16, 38400, 1)
y shape (16, 150, 2)
```

Thanks in advance.